# Project crashes on opening, no edit possible

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2019

Good morning together,

i´ve developed an WIN-Form application in C# Visual Studio 2019.
I´m working there with some usercontrols.

So the problem is now, the project has opened form1 editor. There are already the usercontrols, in one of them is in the loading method an parent function.

Like my usercontrol (OnLoad) - Parent myParent = Parent.this(form1) or similar, the problem is, the usercontrol loads before form1 loads, the usercontrol codes run already in the designer, so it come to a crash, how can i delete now the code from my usercontrol? It´s still not possible to edit something, i open and 1 second later freeze and crash.

Best regards from Germany

Comment: Can you show the code in the user control and the form? What code is running in the load functions?

Comment: I can describe it, but actually i cant copy it, because it kicks me out before.
So in the Form1.cs there are only public methods to call them from the usercontrols. Like: Usercontrol.BringToFront(); Nothing more there.

Comment: Right click on your user control and click on view code, does that also kick you out? Do the same for the form.

Comment: And this is on load in the usercontrol:
Form1 myParent = (Form1)this.Parent;
string Username = Form1.Username;

Comment: It already kicks me out when i open the project, i cant do anything..

Comment: Go the the project location on your PC, open the files in notepad or notepad++ or any other text editor you like

Comment: Done, i opened there the usercontrol.cs which i need, edited the code there.

The problem is, the ,,old" usercontrol is the one which loaded in the editor, i have to click in the Tab on ,,Generate" and ,,Generate Project new" to load the new usercontrol code in the editor

Comment: Do you know how i can deactivate it that the usercontrol code already runs in my editor?

Answer (score 0):

Okey guys i got it.

Thanks @Paul Karam for the help.

I editet the .cs file allone with an editor and deleted the bad lines.
After i opened my full project again, it kicks me out and out, i spammed F6 to rebuild the project, then it crashed again and reloaded and then i spammed STRG + S to save the rebuild.

I think this will be not the best way, but it does his job.